# Why doesn't my inherited interface use my base class's override?

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a problem with interfaces and multiple inheritance. I hope to design my program such that one update call processes a variety of objects, with each behavioral 'building block' tucked away in a single function.

For example, I'd like to move a creature from point A to B in one place, regardless of whether it must perform pre/post move actions. But, my multiple inheritance scheme fails (below, with the bug rem'd), making me think I'd need to duplicate code somewhere.

Clearly I don't understand this well enough! (but I'm working hard to learn it)

Q1. Why can't IPhysics::Move 'see' Creature::Move(), in the CreatureAirborne class?

Q2. Am I completely missing the proper usage of interfaces and/or multiple inheritance? If so, any guidance is appreciated!

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

class IGameObject
{
public:
    virtual ~IGameObject() {}

    virtual void Update() = 0;
};

class IPhysics
{
public:
    virtual ~IPhysics() {}

    virtual void Move() = 0;
};

class IPhysicsFlight : public IPhysics
{
public:
    virtual ~IPhysicsFlight() {}

    virtual void Land() = 0;
    virtual void TakeOff() = 0;
};

class Creature : public IGameObject, IPhysics
{
protected:
    virtual void Move() {}

public:
    Creature() {}
    virtual ~Creature() {}

    virtual void Update() {}
};


class CreatureAirborne : public Creature, IPhysicsFlight
{
private:
    virtual void Land() {}
    virtual void TakeOff() {}

public:
    CreatureAirborne() {}
    virtual ~CreatureAirborne() {}

    virtual void Update();
};

void CreatureAirborne::Update()
{
    TakeOff();

    Creature::Move();

    Land();
}

int main()
{
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Creature>> creatures;

    std::shared_ptr<Creature> cow(new Creature);

    creatures.push_back(cow);

// The butterfly fails to compile with 'cannot instantiate; void IPhysics::Move(void) is abstract'

//  std::shared_ptr<CreatureAirborne> butterfly(new CreatureAirborne);

//  creatures.push_back(butterfly);

    for (auto i : creatures)
    {
        i->Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why Move is **protected** in Creature and **public** in IPhysics? I fear this is causing some issue because I don't think you can restrain visibility so compiler might think you define another function. Not sure, not a C++ guru. :)

Comment: See [Diamond Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

Comment: @MarkRansom: you're right, I've been fooled by C#/Java/all the other languages... :)

Comment: Uhm... why should it? Clearly an airborne creature cannot move as the non-airborne creatur does... ;)

Comment: You are aware that in `class Creature : public IGameObject, IPhysics` the inheritance from `IPhysics` is private?

Comment: @Mark Ransom - I did not know enough about the diamond problem. Thank you!

Comment: @celtschk - I did not realize that was private. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat had to follow your hierarchy, but it looks correct evaluation on the compiler's part.

You don't have virtual inheritance anywhere, so `CreatureAirborne` will have duplicated base classes from some point. You will have two instances of IPhysics. Move, that is abstract from there is implemented on the  Creature branch but remains abstract on IPhysicsFlight.

You can cure the situation by using virtual inheritance somewhere, or by implementing Move in descendant (say just calling the parent version where it exists).

Comment: +1, note that inheritance from pure interfaces should probably be virtual (even from empty bases with logic it can make sense if you don't need multiple bases) as it does not incur extra costs and fixes this type of problems.

Comment: @Balog Pal - That branch terminology helps. I forgot that IPhysicsFlight does not 'go through' Creature, but rather sits beside it in the hierarchy. So I will have to write CreatureAirborn::Move(), after all, I take it? But it can call Creature::Move(), which is good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at things little differently

```
class CreatureAirborne : public IPhysicsFlight,Creature
```

While the code runs

```
new CreatureAirborne ()
```

The compiler will try to build IPhysicsFlight base class and Creature base class and the fact that IPhysics is a base class to both doesn't play any role rather than confusing.As far as compiler is concerned IPhysicsFlight is abstract and CreatureAirborne did not implement Move

The diamond issue will actually come into play when you do a

```
(new CreatureAirborne ())->Move()
```